# Raspbian : Failed to change fw-clk-arm frequency

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I boot my raspberry pi 3B+ with raspbian, it seems to try to change the clock frequency, but it failed.
And the system loop at this state of boot.

> Raspberrypi-clk soc:firmware:clocks: failed to change fw-clk-arm frequency: -110

Please, look at the picture for more details about the error.

[image: picture : Logs at boot]
(sorry I'm new, Stack doesn't allow me to post image)

I tried to install a clean version of raspbian (the last one, kernel 5.4) but the problem is still present. Of course, I can't interact and use CLI.

after a while of looping on the same error (shown in the previous picture)
It displays :

> raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: mbox_send_message returned -62

And then nothing more

Do you have any idea how to manage this error ?

Comment: Seeing same issue on a fresh install. How can we escalate to Rasbperry Pi folks?

Comment: Are you out of disk space by any chance? (you can check that with `df -h`)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and have plenty of disk space. My Pi 3B is a few years old and sat for a while, but was working fine the last time I used it. When I tried the new Raspberry Pi OS, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post that I was having the same issue with one of my Compute Module 4s (a Lite model, no eMMC).

I tried booting it, but it would show the same error:

```
failed to change fw-clk-arm frequency: -110
```

After a couple minutes it would show a message about the kernel being tainted and wouldn't boot further. I remembered I had loaded a beta eeprom onto this particular unit in the past, but it had never had an issue until now. I had already tried wiping and reinstalling Pi OS using the Pi Imager utility a couple times, and that had no effect.

But I [updated my CM4's EEPROM/bootloader](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/how-update-raspberry-pi-compute-module-4-bootloader-eeprom) to make sure it was back on the normal (non-old-beta) version, and then re-flashed Pi OS and it booted right up normal again.

So one possibility *could* be the bootloader is broken somehow. Note that older Pi's don't have a separate EEPROM chip like the Pi 4/400/CM4 does. So for those, maybe it is a hardware issue :(

Comment: Back again a couple months later. Apparently I'm very good at breaking my Raspberry Pis, because I had the exact same problem again, and the solution was to re-flash a known-good EEPROM.